# How to unstyle styled macro in headings?

Tags: macros, sectioning, pdftex, koma-script

I have a macro that occurs very frequently in the text. At one occasion, it occurs inside a heading, which causes some problems:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand\FrequentlyUsedMacro{\emph{\textbf{Macro}}}
\begin{document}

\section{Random section}
This section has the preferred font in its title.\\
Also, very many \FrequentlyUsedMacro{}s.

\section{\FrequentlyUsedMacro{}}
This section also has the right font, but causes warnings.

\section{\textrm{\FrequentlyUsedMacro{}}}
This removes the warnings, but the font is now wrong.

\end{document}
```

This outputs the following:

[image: Latex output with different heading font styles]

Section 2 gives the following warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Why is there a warning if it is obviously possible in section 3? Or does it just not have an italic sans-serif font?

Additional information: if `{article}` is used instead of `{scrartcl}`, the warnings are gone and both headings 2 and 3 are italic. Also, the problem stays the same if `\textbf{}` is removed from the macro.

This is a part of a larger document so I would like to get rid of the warnings. Is there a way to keep the headings both style- and warning-free? I am quite sure there is, but I could not find it via the search function.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You answered the question basically yourself: The font just don't have bold italic sans-serif characters. The change from KOMA to article and vice-versa is change of font families too. You would get the warning in `article` class as well if you `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, but there surely is a way to say "I'd like to have this macro without any of the pre-defined font styles", right? I thought, \textrm{} does this, but apparently not...

Comment: You can change the rules for when a font is not available. Which output, or better behaviour, are you expecting to happen?

Comment: `\textrm` changes back to Roman family, which isn't sans serif of course. You could use `lmodern` package. The warning will vanish then completely, regardless, which `\rmdefault` you use

Comment: @Johannes_B basically, I need a command that strips the macro from its font styles. \text{} and \textnormal{} and even \textsf{} do not yield the intended results

@ChristianHupfer using `lmodern` causes the macro headings to be italic, and I don't know how to prevent that

Comment: Once again the question: What do expect? You are writing in the question that the font is wrong. It is not, it is the font that is substituted by default if the cont demanded does not exist.

Comment: @Johannes_B okay, the font is not _wrong_, it is just not the font that I planned to obtain. What I want is just the font as from the other headings. Sorry if I have been unprecise here

Comment: @Brokenmind So, if you say that with standard classes the problem goes away… does that mean that you don't care if the sectioning font is sans serif or serif? In that case, adding to the preamble `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}` should be enough. And, in case that doesn't please you, I still don't understand. What would be the perfect output? I mean, you want to strip away the formatting *just because you are getting a warning*? Or is it really because you really want it to loose its formatting?

Comment: The whole question is  unclear to me

Comment: I think he just wants the effect of `\emph` to go away inside the section headings. I think a different approach would be defining `\newcommand\FrequentlyUsedMacroText{Macro}` and `\newcommand\FrequentlyUsedMacro{\emph{\textbf{\FrequentlyUsedMacroText}}}` and then using `\section{\FrequentlyUsedMacroText}`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is not clear enough. You are having a problem which you don't completely understand and you are asking for a particular solution that might not be what you *really* want. So here are a few shots in case one is exactly what you are looking for.

The problem is that there's no sans serif bold italic in that particular font that comes by default, Computer Modern Sans Serif (may be there isn't even an italic non-bold font).

You said that with `article` class the problem goes away, “the warnings are gone and both headings 2 and 3 are italic”. If that means that you don't really care about the headings being sans serif (which is the default in `scrartcl`), then

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

should solve your problems.

If you *do* want bold sans serif in the title, then that sentence I quoted is wrong, it doesn't solve your problem just using `article`. In that case, do you want to have the `\verycommonmacro` to output in roman bold italic or in sans serif bold italic. In the first case you can redefine the macro

```
\newcommand*\verycommonmacro{\textrm{\emph{\textbf{Macro}}}}
```

or, if you want it to output sans serif bold italic, you need a font that has that particular shape. As Christian suggested, `lmodern` provides that.

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

(But you say that you get everything in italic? I don't know then what your problem is.)

The last option is what you asked, to strip away any formatting from that macro. (I forgot the code for this one.) In that case, you can set a flag inside of titles, and then let the macro check that flag, and, in case it's ON do something and if it's not do something else. In this case, with the help of `etoolbox`, if it's in a title it inserts `\relax` and if it's not, it uses `\emph`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{insection}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\toggletrue{insection}}
\newcommand*\verycommonmacro
  {\iftoggle{insection}{Macro}{\emph{\bfseries Macro}}}
```

## So, what exactly do you want?

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailed answer! The way I would prefer it actually is number 4. As for the `article` class, “the warnings are gone and both headings 2 and 3 are italic”, but the problem does not go away because italic is not what I wanted. It seems I made some grave mistakes in formulating the question... Solution number 4 is the section with the `etoolbox`, right?

Comment: Yep, solution 4 is the code with `etoolbox` I just showed a basic example with `\iftoggle`, you can play with it in whatever way you want. Its syntax is `\iftoggle{insection}{<code that appears if we are inside a section>}{<else>}` so after that macro expands you get `\relax{\bfseries Macro}` in a section and `\emph{\bfseries Macro}` in any other place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm not very experienced with this type of commands. In any case, that's way more than I hoped for (I thought I would need to _deactivate_ the style manually in the section header), so I'll gladly accept this as the answer. One last question (just curious): Is something like `\iftoggle{insection}{\relax}{\emph\bfseries}{Macro}` possible?

Comment: May be clearer to you is `\iftoggle{insection}{Macro}{\emph{\bfseries Macro}}`, what I used is some sort of hackish shortcut. You can't do what you are doing, because `\emph` takes an argument. What I did was `\iftoggle{insection}{\relax}{\emph}` which in turn, expands to whatever but the next thing *is* a group `{\bfseries Macro}` which becomes the argument of `\emph` (if we are out of a header). TL;DR: I would use a clearer definition if I were you: `\iftoggle{insection}{Macro}{\emph{\bfseries Macro}}`.

Comment: Now that you point it out like this, it seems kind of obvious. That version is indeed much clearer; I will go with it.

Comment: In fact, I don't know why I used that weird definition before :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion using `\newkomafont` to define a font style for this element. This also works if there is a table of contents.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newkomafont{frequentlyusedmacro}{\bfseries\itshape}
\newcommand*\FrequentlyUsedMacro{{\protect\usekomafont{frequentlyusedmacro}Macro}}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\setkomafont{frequentlyusedmacro}{}}
\BeforeStartingTOC{\setkomafont{frequentlyusedmacro}{}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Random section}
This section has the preferred font in its title.\\
Also, very many \FrequentlyUsedMacro{}s.
\section{\FrequentlyUsedMacro{}}
This section also has the right font, but causes warnings.
\section{\FrequentlyUsedMacro}
\subsection{\FrequentlyUsedMacro}
This removes the warnings, but the font is now wrong.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a few solutions which I do *not* think are very clean. However, they might suit your needs:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand\FrequentlyUsedMacro{\emph{\textbf{Macro}}}

\newcommand{\startnoemph}{\let\emph\relax}

\begin{document}

\section{\startnoemph \FrequentlyUsedMacro{}}
This works with \FrequentlyUsedMacro{}.

\end{document}
```

Or:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand\FrequentlyUsedMacro{\emph{\textbf{Macro}}}

\newcommand{\noemph}[1]{\begingroup\let\emph\relax#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\section{\noemph{\FrequentlyUsedMacro{}}}
This works with \FrequentlyUsedMacro{}.

\end{document}
```

I'm sure there is a possibility to use the package `etoolbox` to patch `\section` so that this works automatically.

Comment: As you assumed, there was some way to do it with the `etoolbox` package, and it appears to be cleaner... Nonetheless, I'm sure I encounter some situations where your code comes in handy, so thanks for pointing it out!